# Save model every 10 epochs tensorflow.keras v2

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm using keras defined as submodule in tensorflow v2. I'm training my model using `fit_generator()` method. I want to save my model every 10 epochs. How can I achieve this?

In Keras (not as a submodule of tf), I can give `ModelCheckpoint(model_savepath,period=10)`. But in tf v2, they've changed this to `ModelCheckpoint(model_savepath, save_freq)` where `save_freq` can be `'epoch'` in which case model is saved every epoch. If `save_freq` is integer, model is saved after so many samples have been processed. But I want it to be after 10 epochs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` use `save_freq='epoch'` and pass an extra argument `period=10`.

Although this is not documented in the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), that is the way to do it (notice it is documented that you can pass `period`, just doesn't explain what it does).

Comment: I get the below warning: `WARNING:tensorflow:'period' argument is deprecated. Please use 'save_freq' to specify the frequency in number of samples seen.`
So, I guess, this feature is going out soon. In that case, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe that the only alternative is to calculate the number of examples per epoch, and pass that integer to `save_freq` times the number of epochs you want as interval between saves

Comment: @bluesummers "examples per epoch" This should be my batch size, right?

Comment: Examples per epoch is how many *samples* you want to pass through the network between checkpoints - this means if you have 100 samples (samples != batch, batch is a batch of samples) and you put 400, it will save every 4 epochs

Comment: I had the same question as asked by @NagabhushanSN. I calculated the number of samples per epoch to calculate the number of samples after which I want to save the model but it does not seem to work. Batch size=64, for the test case I am using 10 steps per epoch. If I want to save the model every 3 epochs, the number of samples is 64*10*3=1920. I use that for sav_freq but the output shows that the model is saved on epoch 1, epoch 2, epoch 9, epoch 11, epoch 14 and still running. Can't make sense of it. `period` option seems to work fine but with the message that it will be deprecated.

Comment: For me, `save_freq='epoch', period=10` doesn't work, i.e., after 10 epochs nothing gets saved. Looking at [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), when `save_freq` is given an integer, the callback saves the model at end of this many batches. So it should be: the number of epochs times number of batches per epoch (and not times number of examples per epoch, as @bluesummers said). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @nim.py interestring - what is the data format you are using? is it a `tf.data.Dataset`? Numpy arrays? Is it a generator?

Comment: @bluesummers I am using a numpy array. On Tensorflow version 2.2.0, Keras 2.4.3. Maybe it doesn't work cause `period` is deprecated?

Comment: @nim.py yes, the doc says that model is saved after `save_freq` number of batches. However, with a generator of `batch_size = 16`, `steps_per_epoch = 100` and `save_freq=20`, I expected to see checkpoints corresonding to 0,20,40....th batches, but after running the code, I see checkpoints for every 2nd batch ie (1,3,5,7.....). I really can't make any sense of how this works.

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly computing the number of batches per epoch worked for me.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 20
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = train_labels.size / BATCH_SIZE
SAVE_PERIOD = 10

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights every 10 epochs
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_path, 
    verbose=1, 
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_freq= int(SAVE_PERIOD * STEPS_PER_EPOCH))

# Train the model with the new callback
model.fit(train_images, 
          train_labels,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
          epochs=50, 
          callbacks=[cp_callback],
          validation_data=(test_images,test_labels),
          verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

The param `period` mentioned in the accepted answer is now not available anymore.

Using the `save_freq` param is an alternative, but risky, as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint); e.g., if the dataset size changes, it may become unstable: *Note that if the saving isn't aligned to epochs, the monitored metric may potentially be less reliable* (again taken from the docs).

Thus, I use a subclass as a solution:

```
class EpochModelCheckpoint(tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint):

    def __init__(self,
                 filepath,
                 frequency=1,
                 monitor='val_loss',
                 verbose=0,
                 save_best_only=False,
                 save_weights_only=False,
                 mode='auto',
                 options=None,
                 **kwargs):
        super(EpochModelCheckpoint, self).__init__(filepath, monitor, verbose, save_best_only, save_weights_only,
                                                   mode, "epoch", options)
        self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
        self.frequency = frequency

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.epochs_since_last_save += 1
        # pylint: disable=protected-access
        if self.epochs_since_last_save % self.frequency == 0:
            self._save_model(epoch=epoch, batch=None, logs=logs)

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        pass
```

use it as

```
callbacks=[
     EpochModelCheckpoint("/your_save_location/epoch{epoch:02d}", frequency=10),
]
```

Note that, dependent on your TF version, you may have to change the args in the call to the superclass `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for this answer too and wanted to point out a couple changes from previous answers. I am using TF version 2.5.0 currently and `period=` is working but only if there is no `save_freq=` in the callback.

```
my_callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=path
        period=N
    )
]
```

This is working for me with no issues even though period is not documented in the callback documentation

Comment: Thanks for the update. Hasn't it been removed yet? It was marked as deprecated and I would imagine it would be removed by now. Is it still deprecated?

Comment: As of TF Ver 2.5.0 it's still there and working. It is still shown as deprecated `WARNING:tensorflow:'period' argument is deprecated. Please use 'save_freq' to specify the frequency in number of batches seen.` However it is still saving as it should