# Saving Model Checkpoint in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Tensorflow 2.3 and trying to save model checkpoint after `n` number of epochs. `n` can be anything but for now trying with 10

Per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069058/save-model-every-10-epochs-tensorflow-keras-v2), I tried `save_freq = 'epoch'` and `period = 10` which works but since `period` parameter is deprecated, I wanted to try  an alternative approach.

```
HEIGHT = 256
WIDTH = 256
CHANNELS = 3
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 1
SAVE_PERIOD = 10

n_monet_samples = 21

checkpoint_filepath = "./model_checkpoints/cyclegan_checkpoints.{epoch:03d}"
model_checkpoint_callback = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_freq=SAVE_PERIOD * (n_monet_samples//BATCH_SIZE)
)
```

If I use `save_freq=SAVE_PERIOD * (n_monet_samples//BATCH_SIZE)` for the checkpoint callback definition, I get error

```
ValueError: Unrecognized save_freq: 210
```

I am not sure why since per [Keras callback code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py), as long as `save_freq` is in epochs or in `integer`, it should be good.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It does not show any error to me when I tried the same code in same `Tensorflow version==2.3`:

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
BATCH_SIZE = 1
SAVE_PERIOD = 10

n_monet_samples = 21

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1, save_freq=SAVE_PERIOD * (n_monet_samples//BATCH_SIZE))

# Train the model with the new callback
model.fit(train_images, 
          train_labels,  
          epochs=20,
          validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
          callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.1152 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.6890 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.7940
Epoch 2/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4154 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8840 - val_loss: 0.5317 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8330
Epoch 3/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2787 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9270 - val_loss: 0.4854 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8400
Epoch 4/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2230 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9420 - val_loss: 0.4525 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8590
Epoch 5/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1549 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9620 - val_loss: 0.4275 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8650
Epoch 6/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1110 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9770 - val_loss: 0.4251 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8630
Epoch 7/20
11/32 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0936 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9886
Epoch 00007: saving model to training_1/cp.ckpt
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0807 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9840 - val_loss: 0.4248 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8610
Epoch 8/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0612 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.4058 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8650
Epoch 9/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0489 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.4393 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8610
Epoch 10/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0361 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4150 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8620
Epoch 11/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0294 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4090 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8670
Epoch 12/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0272 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9990 - val_loss: 0.4365 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8600
Epoch 13/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0203 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4231 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8620
Epoch 14/20
 1/32 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0115 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 00014: saving model to training_1/cp.ckpt
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0164 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4263 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8650
Epoch 15/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0128 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4260 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8690
Epoch 16/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0120 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4194 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8740
Epoch 17/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0110 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4302 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8710
Epoch 18/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0090 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4331 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8660
Epoch 19/20
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0084 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4320 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8760
Epoch 20/20
16/32 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0074 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 00020: saving model to training_1/cp.ckpt
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0072 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.4280 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8750
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f90f0082cd0>
```

As you already know `save_freq` is equal to 'epoch' or integer.
 When using `'epoch'`, the callback saves the model after each epoch. 
When using `integer`, the callback saves the model at end of theses many batches(end of these many steps_per_epoch).

As above definition of save_freq, checkpoints saves every after 210 steps.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint#args) for more details on `ModelCheckpoint` Arguments.